# RGeo::Feature.cast does not convert between projections

Tags: convert, ruby

I am attempting to cast a MultiLineString feature in WGS84 to UTM33N using [RGeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo).

Unfortunately, `RGeo::Feature.cast`, instead of casting the feature to the desired projection, returns the original feature unchanged, as the checks at the end show. Why does the conversion result like this? What else is needed to convert between these two projections in RGeo?

```
require 'rgeo'
require 'rgeo-geojson'

utm_33n_factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 32633, proj4: '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
wgs_84_factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326, proj4: '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')

geo_json = '{"type":"Feature","properties":{"City":"PRG","Name":"Z","Color":"green","Description":"Pohorelec"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[14.389935,50.087667,0],[14.389219,50.08756,0],[14.389093,50.087525,0],[14.388617,50.087394,0]]]}}'
json_geom = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(geo_json, geo_factory: wgs_84_factory, json_parser: :json).geometry
projected = RGeo::Feature.cast json_geom, factory: utm_33n_factory, project: true

puts json_geom.equal? projected # => true
puts projected.srid # => 4326
```

Comment: I just ran this, and it runs as expected.

irb(main):009:0> puts json_geom.equal? projected
false
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> puts projected.srid
32633
=> nil
irb(main):011:0>

Comment: You can always just do an intermediate phase and convert it to a geographic coordinate system then back to the other projected coordinate system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue where RGeo::Feature.cast is not converting between projections.  In my case, it was because my local install of RGeo was not using Proj4.  I suspect that you have the same problem.

Without Proj4 support, a comparison of the two factories evaluates to true.

`utm_33n_factory == wgs_84_factory`

Feature.cast makes this comparison and short circuits any coordinate conversion.  Making sure you are using Proj4 should resolve the issue.

You can also check whether Proj4 is being used by RGeo using the following.

`RGeo::CoordSys::Proj4.supported?`

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a long time since I encountered this issue and I haven't worked with rgeo for ages, but I remember getting a similar advice (which fixed my issue) on a mailing list back then.